# join status history

Tags: sql

I have a table listing patient days for encounters. Below a sample for one encounter. Every day the patient is in the hospital one record is created at midnight untill discharge.

```
Enc_iD  Day_Id      ServiceDtTm        AdmitDate
2616350 34707672    2/21/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34733898    2/22/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34748155    2/23/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34760403    2/24/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34784357    2/25/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34808228    2/26/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
2616350 34814512    2/27/2013 10:10    21/FEB/13 12:19:00
```

In a separate table a status for every encounter is maintained irregulary by a user.

```
Enc_iD  TransDtTm       Status
2616350 2/21/2013 12:20 
2616350 2/21/2013 13:29 1
2616350 2/22/2013 7:28  3
2616350 2/25/2013 13:44 2
2616350 2/27/2013 10:10 2
```

I want to create a resultset with SQL as below. So for every day in the top table the status that was the most recent at that `ServiceDtTm`.

```
Enc_iD  Day_Id      DtTime             AdmitDate            Status
2616350 34707672    2/21/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   1
2616350 34733898    2/22/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   3
2616350 34748155    2/23/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   3
2616350 34760403    2/24/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   3
2616350 34784357    2/25/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   2
2616350 34808228    2/26/2013 23:59    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   2
2616350 34814512    2/27/2013 10:10    21/FEB/13 12:19:00   2
```

Any help is appreciated. Can't figure this out SQL. Only in excel by using vlookup with approximate match.

Robbert

Comment: Show us what you have come up with first. This isn't oDesk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is a correlated subquery.  Here is the syntax in SQL Server:

```
select pd.*,
       (select top  1  status
        from status s 
        where s.enc_id = pd.enc_id and s.transdttm <= pd.servicedttm
        order by s.transdttm
       ) as MostRecentStatus
from patientdays pd
```

For most other databases, it would look like:

```
select pd.*,
       (select status
        from status s 
        where s.enc_id = pd.enc_id and s.transdttm <= pd.servicedttm
        order by s.transdttm
        limit 1
       ) as MostRecentStatus
from patientdays pd
```

Comment: only thing is i cant us limit or top in my system. So i ended up using subquery as you suggested, put than based on the ID. So join status s where pd.enc_id = s.enc_id and s.day_id = (select max(s.day_id) from status s2 where s2.DtTime < pd.ServiceDtTm)

Comment: @user2120786 . . . When an answer solves your problem, you should accept it.  When you have more points, you can upvote as many answer as you like (to your questions or someone else's).

Comment: @user2120786 . . . The syntax depends on the database.  In Oracle, you would add ` and rownum = 1` in the `where` clause, for instance; in db2, it would be another clause like `fetch first 1 row`.